# How to Activate an open application window using the Process Identifier with .VBS or .BAT

Tags: excel, vbscript

My code is simple, I just want to do this:

```
    Set iShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    xRepeat:

    ' ** Activate a specify Internet Explorer 11 Window already open (by PID)
    iShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{CTRL + C}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{TAB} {TAB} {TAB} {TAB}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{CTRL+ V}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{TAB} {TAB} {TAB} {TAB}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{CTRL + V}"

    ' ** Activate a program already open (by PID)
    iShell.SendKeys "{TAB} {TAB} {TAB} {TAB}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{CTRL + C}"

    ' ** Activate a specify Internet Explorer 11 Window already open (by PID)
    iShell.SendKeys "{TAB} {TAB} {TAB} {TAB}"
    iShell.SendKeys "{CTRL + V}"

    If msgbox("Repeat process?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
       GoTo xRepeat
    End if
```

I have some programs opened, and I dont want stay using "SendKeys {ALT + TAB}"

I work in a computer with extremely blocked access and basically my job is fill forms with the same answers all day, so I want fill automatically.

How so the computer that I use has no access to anything, I wish a solution that doesn't need to install anything.

I can use only notepad(.VBS or .BAT). Aah, I Can use VBA too, so the 'automation' above can be in .bat .vbs or in excell.vba as well. I know a lot of VBA, but only to do things into Excel

Ps: I can only get PID by notepad.bat "tasklist; @pause"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a (large) solution. My next goal is dont use {TAB}, I wanna learn how to get to the specific form and put a value. Like: `Document.GetElementByName("username").Value = "ALEXAN"`

But my problem is how to set an already opened Internet Explorer as an Object so then use `.Document.GetElementByName`

> ```
> Dim ws
>
> Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
> If MsgBox("Finalizado?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "") = vbYes Then
>     ws.AppActivate "Tratar Protocolos - Internet Explorer"
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "^{c}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "FINALIZADO"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "SOLICITAÇAO ATENDIDA"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "Finalizado"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{c}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.AppActivate "Siebel eCommunications Produção - Meio de Acesso - \\Remote"
>         MsgBox "Copie o CNPJ depoiso dê OK!"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.AppActivate "Tratar Protocolos - Internet Explorer"
>         WScript.Sleep 300
>     ws.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 300
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 300
>     ws.SendKeys "Protocolo perfilado com sucesso!"
>         WScript.Sleep 300
>     ws.SendKeys "^{a}"
>
> ElseIf MsgBox("Pendente?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "") = vbYes Then
>     ws.AppActivate "Tratar Protocolos - Internet Explorer"
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "^{c}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "PENDENTE"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "STATUS SUSPENSO"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "~"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "0"
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{c}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.AppActivate "Siebel eCommunications Produção - Meio de Acesso - \\Remote"
>         MsgBox "Copie o CNPJ depoiso dê OK!"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.AppActivate "Tratar Protocolos - Internet Explorer"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{v}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "Protocolo perfilado com sucesso!"
>         WScript.Sleep 200
>     ws.SendKeys "^{a}"
> End If
> WScript.Quit
> ```